# Value error when trying to fit a classifier sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with only one feature, and the feature is a 100 size array. When I am trying to fit it using a classifier I get error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think the classifier cannot take an array as features.
When I write
`X.shape --> (10000,)`
I want it to be like `10000,100`
where 100 is the size of the array.

I wanted to know how I can solve this issue?

Link to the [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f8kHn3gvjDd7G4YAQGVpIsqXs55ENf7Y).

Comment: Code please. That would actually help everyone trying to help you

Comment: Please could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to aid the answering of your question.

Comment: I have added a link to the CSV file. I was facing trouble training a classifier on this. When I use fit operation using sklearn.RandomForestClassifier, I get the above-mentioned error.